# Bad hard disk or bad Operating system?

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive

I recently bought a new Seagate 500 GB internal hard disk drive for my desktop and installed Linux (Pear OS). It was working fine for few minutes and then suddenly it hanged. I tried to open directories and got this error message "Failed to execute child process input/output error while read on [path]". I then checked with Disk utility and it shows the same error. I observed my HDD LED on casing was not blinking at all (continuously ON). I rebooted and directly checked with Disk SMART test but found no error. IT was showing that disk was OK. Suddenly after few minutes same problem happened. Then I installed windows 8 on it. It was working fine and suddenly it was frozen. Task manager showed Disk activity 100%. I booted in safe mode and it was working fine. It doesn't show disk activity. I checked my hard drive with most of the tools and nobody showed any kind of error. I did not get what is the problem. Is my Hard drive faulty?

Comment: Try another drive - if the problem persists, then it must be something else. If not, faulty drive

Comment: Are you sure you performed the right S.M.A.R.T. test and interpreted the results correctly? If it's not the hard drive, it could also be a faulty storage controller. Simon's suggestion would be a great way to diagnose the origin of the problem, if you have another drive.

Comment: Right now I don't have another hard disk. Earlier I had one which belonged to my friend and it was working fine. I also checked it with command line seatools. It showed no errors detected.

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. testing is somewhat limited. Which other tools did you try, i.e. Seagate's own diagnostics? How long did you wait for the disk activity to resolve when the light went "solid"? Frankly, the percentage of disk failures when new is much higher than you might think ( http://www.behardware.com/articles/843-6/components-returns-rates-5.html ), not to mention that some models have alarmingly high failure rates -- i.e. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/01/16/barracuda_failure_plague/

Comment: I know this is out of left field, how's your power supply doing?

Comment: @Debra: Seatools for Dos -http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/. It took 2 hours to complete the test.
When light went 'solid', I waited for almost 5-10 minutes and Pc rebooted.Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @RandolphWest: How do I test my power supply?

Comment: Which tool would you recommend to test my hard disk is faulty or not?

Comment: You can often check the power supply first from the CMOS setup;  many computers have built-in monitoring, so at least start there. Seatools is going to be pretty reliable for diagnostics. Frankly, I think you just have a faulty disk & should either exchange it or, if too late for that, contact Seagate for replacement. They'll ask you to run Seatools or another of their diagnostics first, anyway.

Comment: Well thanks for a suggestion. I will replace it. Just out of curiosit- why does it run fine in safe mode?

Comment: in addition to those mentioned there's also the chkdsk command. chkdsk /r will check and "repair" and try to recover anything gone bad(shouldn't add too much time to the thing),(though re repair, it's advised not to use a disk with bad sectors or with too many bad sectors).  chkdsk without /r or /f probably just does a read only scan. note- best way to recover may be making an image and working on that somehow. but anyhow point is, chkdsk, hasn't been mentioned. is built in native to windows.

Comment: Two questions: what do you mean by "while rad on path"? I do not understand the word "rad". Question number two: which file system was mounted on the HD when you installed Linux?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae : It is edited now. I meant to say "read". it was ext2 when I installed linux. Now I have two NTFS partitions plus one ext4 partition.

Comment: @Debra: I replaced that hard drive and faced a similar problem. I noticed the problem appeared whenever my display driver gets updated so I use roll-back to use the previous version of my display driver and it is working fine (At least for now). According to you, what could be the problem?

Comment: Seems to me that you've already said it: the display driver.  They don't all work as they should, and if back-revving it works to resolve your issue, then that's the appropriate thing to do for now (until it gets fixed.)  I don't see this comment - "Just out of curiosit- why does it run fine in safe mode?" noted in your original post, or that would've been a clear clue to the display driver as a #1 suspect. Simon's comment, right at the top, was on target: replace drive & see if that resolves the issue, and if not then it's likely something loading. Glad you worked it out.